# How to save operators in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, operators

**I want to do something like this in dart.**

`var z = +`

**and then put it in another var like this**

`var x = 5 z 5`

**And when I did this**

`var z = +`

**I get an Error**

*Expected an identifier.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not make variable operators in dart though what you can do is to create a custom variable for the same by doing:

```
void main() {
var operators = {
    '+': (a, b) { return a + b; },
    '<': (a, b) { return a < b; },
     // ...
};

var op = '+';
var x = operators[op]!(10, 20);
  print(x);
}
```

Comment: no i mean i whant to change the whole string like this "5 + 5"

Comment: you want to change your whole string into? 10?

Comment: So you want to do `z='+';` | `x='5z5';` and this will return you your desired output?

Comment: yes i want that

Comment: can you explain why you want that? you want to change a string into an operation which will be a lot of work for a simple operation

Comment: i am making a calculator app so when you Presse a button he activate a function with operator and i don't want to make a function to every button because there a lot

Comment: So why don't you set all your operators in the `operators` list as in the code above and then send the two numbers as `x` and `y` in the `operators[op]!(x, y);` and finally just print the output from that

Comment: it doesn't work with many numbers the idea of string that i can time as many as i want of numbers and operators example: x = "5 + 3 - 6" and turn it to this  x = 5 + 3 - 6

Comment: Don't you think you should do two numbers and then add one more again like when the user types 5+3 then convert it using the above code to 8 in the background and then use 8-6 to output 2 instead. The user will be seeing 5+3-6 in the ui but you will be using this simple operation to save your own time and efforts.